# non-blocking read status from an http stream without socket programing

Tags: python

I have to get the response of the http GET request `http://172.19.1.89/command/alarmdata.cgi?interval=1`

The request will continuously respond me the status in a specified interval and open a streaming request from the server.

But my Python script was blocked. because the connection won't be terminated.

How to show the response instantly during the connection ?

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import httplib2
>>> h = httplib2.Http()
>>> h
<httplib2.Http object at 0x108657690>
>>> h.add_credentials('admin','admin')
>>> (resp, content) = h.request('http://172.19.1.89/command/alarmdata.cgi?interval=1', 'GET')
```

Stuck here

Comment: In your example, does `resp` not contain the response?

Comment: yes, but I can not see the result on the console instantly because the connection won't be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer function to fetch data from the server in periodic fashion

```
import threading
t = None

def sayHello():
    # here u can apply ur function to get periodic request ..

    global t
    print "Hello!"
    t = threading.Timer(0.5, sayHello) # set the time interval
    t.start()
sayHello()
```

Comment: In python, comment with `#` not `//`

Comment: thanks for that .here i mean to learn him mechanism .not write him code . any ways i will not do that error next:)

Comment: u can edit my answer . to make the better code. even i can also learn

Comment: Well, a pointer: you initialize `t` before you define it, that's no good